# vb.net filter webbrowser source

Tags: vb.net, browser

im looking for a way to filter the source code of a web page as it comes in (i can change it after the page has been loaded but in this case it is useless since i want to flip an autoplay attribute from 1 to 0), is there a way to do this?

Alternatively i could get the source, do the modifications and then write to a new document but this would require a lot of extra filtering to set all the "/blah blah" type locations to "webpage.com/blah blah". Is there any way to trick the browser into thinking the page is from an external server not localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write it out to a temp file.  You can read ("get the source") and pre-process the HTML ("autoplay attribute from 1 to 0") and then assign it to the WebBrowser.DocumentText property to display the page.

Comment: I dont write it to a file anyway and as explained if i write it into the browser it assumes its host to be local which breaks the page.